# Select whole element nested inside contenteditable even if only part of it gets selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a contenteditable div with some span tags nested within it. The thing what I have to do is select whole element even if only a part gets selected and it should work with both - clicking mouse and dragging as well as holding shift + navigation keys.
The layout could look something like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="text">
     Some text goes here
     <span class="highlight">Some tag in here</span>
     Some more text
     <span class="highlight">More tagged text</span>
</div>
```

What im tring to do is ill have a "tags" inside the text that shouldn't be editable but you could still copy them together with rest of the text.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding `contenteditable="false"` to the `<span>`s? - http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/erdtwp3p/

Comment: As a general idea, what I veliece you want to do is `document.getSelection` or `window.getSelection` (based on the browser) to get the selection on the page. Next iterate through each of the selected node's parent nodes until you find a common parent node among all of the nodes that were selected. And if I understand you correctly you also want to make sure the common parent has a `nodeType = 1`.